# Can't change ComboBox selection when bound to ObservableCollection (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create an edit form for editing properties of a custom set of TV Series objects.  One of the properties holds a collection of all owned media formats (DVD, Blu-ray, etc) for that particular series that will be displayed in a `ComboBox`.    Items are added to the `ComboBox` via a separate popup window and items are to be removed from the `ComboBox` by selecting the item and clicking a remove `Button`.

I can add new entries to the MediaOwned `ComboBox` just fine, but when I try to select a specific `ComboBox` item to test the remove `Button` I find that I can only ever select the first entry. Can someone please tell me if I've missed something embarrassingly obvious, thanks.

Here is the problematic property:

```cs
    private ObservableCollection<string> _mediaOwned = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> MediaOwned
    {
        get { return _mediaOwned; }
        set
        {
            _mediaOwned = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MediaOwned"));
        }
    }
```

Here are the other relevant code behind:

```cs
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create binding for the ListBox.
        Binding listBinding = new Binding();
        listBinding.Source = show.Series;
        listBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        listBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        lbSeries.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, listBinding);

        // Create binding for the ComboBox.
        Binding myBinding = new Binding();
        myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("MediaOwned");
        myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        cbMediaOwned.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
    }

    private void btnRemoveMedia_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Series series = (Series)lbSeries.SelectedItem;
        series.MediaOwned.Remove(cbMediaOwned.Text);
    }
```

And here is the XAML code:

```xml
        <Border Style="{StaticResource PanelBorderStyle}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="0,8,8,0" 
                DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lbLists, Path=SelectedItem}">
            <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ListBox x:Name="lbSeries" Style="{StaticResource BasicListStyle}" Width="180" Height="300" 
                             DisplayMemberPath="Title" SelectionMode="Single" LayoutUpdated="lbSeries_LayoutUpdated">
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
                
                <StackPanel x:Name="editPanel" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lbSeries, Path=SelectedItem}">
                    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0, 4, 0, 0">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SmallFont}" Width="100">Title</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtTitle" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" Margin="8, 8, 16, 8"></TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SmallFont}" Width="100">Media owned</TextBlock>

                        <ComboBox x:Name="cbMediaOwned" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"  Width="150" Margin="8,8,6,8" 
                                ></ComboBox>

                        <Button x:Name="btnAddMedia" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarButtonStyle}" Click="btnAddMedia_Click" Margin="0">
                            <StackPanel ToolTip="Add media">
                                <Image Source="Images/add.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="btnRemoveMedia" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarButtonStyle}" Click="btnRemoveMedia_Click" Margin="4">
                            <StackPanel ToolTip="Remove media">
                                <Image Source="Images/remove.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
```

Alternatively I can also remove the binding code in the code behind and replace the `ComboBox` with the below code (but I still get the same problem - I can't select anything in the `ComboBox`):

```
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cbMediaOwned" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"  Width="150" Margin="8,8,6,8" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lbSeries, Path=SelectedItem.MediaOwned, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMedia, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>
```

SelectedMedia property:

```
    private string _selectedMedia = "";
    public string SelectedMedia
    {
        get { return _selectedMedia; }
        set
        {
            _selectedMedia = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedMedia"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The ItemsSource and the SelectedItem need to be bound to two different properties.

Comment: I added SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMedia, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" and the related property but it didn't make a difference.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: I don't do it all from code behind the way you do so it is a little hard to follow. I will post what I do in an answer and see if you can translate that to the way you do it.

Comment: How about we simplify this a little and start with this: <ComboBox x:Name="cbMediaOwned"
ItemsSource="{Binding MediaOwned}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMedia}"/>

Comment: Same problem, can't select different items in ComboBox.  I don't seem to be getting anywhere with this, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Models_ComboBox"
      Width="110"
      Text="Model"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Model"
      MouseDoubleClick="Models_ComboBox_MouseDoubleClick"
      SelectionChanged="Models_ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Here are my VM properties:

```
private DataTable models;
public DataTable Models
{
    get { return models; }
    set
    {
        if (models != value)
        {
            models = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Models));
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
private DataRowView selectedModel;
public DataRowView SelectedModel
{
    get { return selectedModel; }
    set
    {
        if (selectedModel != value)
        {
            selectedModel = value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                InitializeOptions(value["Model"].ToString());
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedModel));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the ItemsSource and the SelectedItem of the ComboBox are bound to two different properties in the ViewModel. The ItemsSource is bound to a DataTable populated from a Database. Once the user selects a Model, then there are other option ComboBoxes that are populated based on that selection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in your case wouldn't the ComboBox list ALL the available models?  That isn't what I want.  In my version the ComboBox is only supposed to hold the media formats owned for that particular TV series.

Comment: @ChrisUK You can use whatever logic you want to populate the ComboBox. I'm just showing how to separate the ItemsSource from the SelectedItem.

Comment: For example if was making a car database I might have a property for optional extras like sunroof, spoiler, alloy wheels, etc. The ComboBox would only hold the all the extras included with that particular car.

Comment: I can populate the ComboBox just fine, I just can't select different items in it once it's populated.

Comment: @ChrisUK That is why I am saying that you need to separate the binding for the ItemsSource from the binding for the SelectedItem.

Comment: I've added to the end of my original post an alternative piece of code that sets up the binding in the XAML rather than the code behind, but I still get the same problem - but it may help you spot any issues.  ItemsSource and SelectedItem are bound to different properties as you can see.

Comment: @ChrisUK Can you add to you post the property SelectedMedia? Thanks.

Comment: OK, added.  Thanks again for your help btw - I'm sure I'm doing something really stupid somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem myself.  I had a line of code that was automatically setting the `SelectedIndex` of the `ComboBox` without me realizing.